# Boot fails after "apt-get upgrade"

Tags: grub2, upgrade, vmware, initramfs

I've been trying to migrate a VM from Virtual Box (never using that garbage ever again) to VMWare.
I was able to import the VM into VMWare and get it to boot.

Once I get into VMWare I run a simple `apt-get update` & `apt-get upgrade`.

Everything goes fine. I get a prompt for `configuring grub-pc`. I have tried all checked combination on that configuration and the outcome is the same. Finally I reboot the VM.

At boot, I get the grub prompt and select ubuntu, all good!

Now a few seconds later, the OS doesn't boot and I get a screen saying `Gave up waiting for root file system device.` with this error `ALERT! UUID=X does not exist. Dropping to a shell!`:

[image: vmware]

**Any idea what I could do?** I can always reload the VM and do something different after the `apt-get upgrade` and before I reboot.

The really strange thing is that there is no `/dev/sda` or `/dev/sda1` when I try to `ls /dev/sd*`

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess that the UUIDs of the filesystems have changed somehow during the migration process.

After the migration attempt, prior to apt-get update / upgrade, have you looked at /etc/defaults/grub (where boot-time filesystem arguments may reside) and /etc/fstab (where filesystems may be named by partition or by UUID)?

Something is going wrong in the translation between what VMWare is presenting as hardware, what the kernel labels (via the output of the `mount` command, or looking in /proc/mounts) and what grub is looking for when it reboots.

If you can get those things in harmony it should work.

I can't guess further without more information, but I'll try to respond to comments if you provide more information in your question about what Ubuntu version you are using, what the contents of /etc/fstab are, and what /etc/defaults/grub looks like, as well as any information about the partition label and UUID of the root filesystem